# How to update reactive object without losing reactivity (vue3 compositionAPI)

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I tryed to update a reactive object , but reactivity is lost.

How to solve this problem?

```js
const obj = reactive({ id:0 , name: "Tom" })


const updateObj = { id:1 , name: "Bob" }

Object.keys(updateObj).forEach(key => {
   obj[key] = updateObj[key]
 })


console.log( isRef( obj.id ) )  // => false
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually your example should work, when it comes to reactivity. Instead of iterating through the keys, it might be a better idea to simply use `Object.assign(obj, updateObj)`, but your approach should work as well.

But, it seems you have a slight misconception about reactivity and the `isRef` function: `isRef` does not check if the given argument is reactive, but specifically if it is a `ref` object (see [this section](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#isref) in the Vue docs). There is also a function called `isReactive` that can check specifically, if an object is a `reactive` object (see [here](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-utilities.html#isreactive)). Note, that this does also not return true for the property of a reactive object.

I've created a [small example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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), that should illustrate the difference between the two methods. It also shows, that reactivity works, even if the `isRef` and `isReactive` functions both return `false`:

```html
<script setup>
import { computed, reactive, ref, isReactive, isRef } from 'vue';
  
const obj = reactive({ id: 0 , name: "Tom" })
const realRef = ref('foo')

const isRefOrReactive = computed(() => ({
  objRef: isRef(obj),
  objReactive: isReactive(obj),
  objIdRef: isRef(obj.id),
  objIdReactive: isReactive(obj.id),
  refRef: isRef(realRef),
  refReactive: isReactive(realRef)
}))

const updateObject = () => {
  const updateObj = { id: 1 , name: "Bob" }
  Object.keys(updateObj).forEach(key => {
    obj[key] = updateObj[key]
  })
  // Object.assign(obj, updatedObj)
}
</script>

<template>
  <pre>{{ obj }}</pre>
  <pre>{{ obj.name }}</pre>
  <pre>{{ isRefOrReactive }}</pre>
  <button @click="updateObject">
    Swap data
  </button>
</template>
```

Comment: I misunderstood `isReactive` and `isRef`.

It worked fine with `isReactive (obj)`.
Thank you for making an example. 

It was a great learning because you explained it carefully.